# TF400324 Team Foundation services are not available

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

i have a problem in team foundation when i want connect to tfs server with VS.

error at connect time :

```
TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server <URL>.
Technical information (for administrator):
The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseHeader Detail=Header name is invalid
```

but i connect with browser to tfs server and can't connect with VS.

tnx to all :)

Comment: Have you tried with other client machines? Can you reproduce the issue on other machines?

Comment: i can connect with my user account on another systems and also with browser on my system, i get this error only when i want to connect with my vs with, it is not just for my user, i tried to connect with another credential on my vs and i get this error again

Comment: "`i can connect with my user account on another systems`" Do you mean that you can connect with VS on another system? If it is,then it should be the specific issue on your environment...

Comment: yes, this is a problem on my visual studio,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clear both local TFS cache and Visual Studio Cache, then try it again.

1. ​Close all Visual Studio instances.
2. clear visual studio cache under

   ```
   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
   ```
3. clear TFS cache under

   ```
   %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\{version}\Cache
   ```
4. Go to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Manage your Credential ->
   Windows Credential, select the TFS url to remove it.
5. Restart your Visual Studio to re-connect to your TFS Server.

If that still not work, just try adding following code to your TFS `web.config` file (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\web.config`):

```
<configuration>
      <system.net>
            <settings>
                  <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
            </settings>
      </system.net>
</configuration>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Try below things :

- Run below command to reset the user data, then try it again.

  `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`,

  `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`
- Try run as another user with command: `runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`
- Reset IIS and application pool

If that still not work, I suggest removing the VS first
   (clean uninstall), then reinstall it again..

Comment: I have tried all of this steps and none of them does not solve my problem

Comment: @mostafa Just try running below command to reset the user data, then try it again. `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`, then `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`

Comment: I did this a minute ago and now vs crashed on start up

Comment: @mostafa Sorry about that, however it should be the VS issue. Try run as another user with command: `runas /netonly /user:<account> devenv.exe`
If that still not work, I suggest removing the VS first (clean uninstall), then reinstall it again....

Comment: my vs is now ok, I resets iis and application pool of my tfs and it is works fine and I connected to my tfs, thanks