# Problem connecting Visual Studio 2019 to TFS 2010 when disconnected from Internet

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

There is solution for connecting VS2019 to TFS 2010 similar to our situation,
[How to connect Visual Studio 2019 to TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297628/how-to-connect-visual-studio-2019-to-tfs)
In our case the servers and computers are on a local network, intentionally disconnected from the Internet.
VS seems to want the server hosted as an Azure DevOps Server.
Is there any way to connect VS2019 to a local TFS server without the Internet?

In the "Connect to a Project" dialog there are no hosted repositories listed for my account (as expected).
When I attempt to add the TFS server in the "Connect to a Project" dialog, the error is:
Server was not added.
HTTP code 504: Gateway Timeout

Comment: I was able to get a little farther using an HTTPS URL for the TFS server.  The error code returned when I attempt to add TFS as an Azure DevOps Server is now
TF400324: Azure DevOps services are not available from server.  This makes sense because it's an old TFS server.  I tried suggestions from this solution:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177439/tf400324-team-foundation-services-are-not-available> but so far no luck.

Comment: Can you succeed to login the web portal from same machine where the VS exists?

Comment: No, but the web portal does not work well from any workstation.  It worked in the past but then stopped working and no one here has the knowledge to do much with IIS issues.  We normally only use TFS through Visual Studio, so that has not been a problem.

Comment: Have you checked whether the tfs collection is running via TFS administrator console?

Comment: I tried the witadmin command "witadmin listwitd /collection:https://myTFSserver.com/tfs/MyProjectCollection /p:MyProject".  It delayed a minute or two and then returned "TF400324: Azure DevOps services are not available from server".  I can do the same widadmin query on an existing workstation (running VS2010) and the witadmin query suceeds, returning the expected categories.

Comment: It looks like I can connect VS2019 to TFS2010, but it requires taking off the SSL requirement on TFS.  If I open the TFS server to non-SSL connections, then I can connect with witadmin and a browser and VS2019 by specifying the URL as http://1.2.3.4:8080/tfs.  I tried this because when I tried to connect with a browser, it would fail with a vague message about TLS.  I'm guessing the old TFS2010 server does not support TLS.  This server is intentionally disconnected from the Internet, so this may be a workable solution for now.  Does anyone know if TFS2010 should support TLS?

Comment: Glad to know you've found a workaround to resolve this issue, you can [add it as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that members with similar issue could benefit from that.

Comment: As for whether TFS2010 should support TLS, it seems there's something wrong with TFS2010+TLS1.2, see similar discussions here.([link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1215c95-3ee9-4efe-a2af-fb629e254858/microsoft-team-foundation-server-2010-tls-12-issue?forum=tfsgeneral),[link2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eae7cb99-abc2-43d0-9664-c6770b5b4f24/why-does-enabling-tls-12-prevent-signin-to-team-foundation-service-for-ie-9-vs-2010-sp1-and-vs?forum=TFService))

Comment: It may be that Visual Studio on your machine is enforcing higher SSL/TLS security settings than the server hosting TFS supports. Tis may be enforced on your workstation through group policy. The client (your Visual Studio Machine) must have at least 1 cypher suite config in common with the server. And that suite must be valid for the certificate on the server as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls

Comment: Any special reason you're not upgrading the TFS 2010 server to Azure DevOps Server 2019? or any supported version in between?

Answer (score 1):

I can connect VS2019 to TFS2010, but it requires taking off the SSL requirement on TFS. If I open the TFS server to non-SSL connections, then I can connect with witadmin and a browser and VS2019 by specifying the URL as http://1.2.3.4:8080/tfs.